# PHP problem with insert into database in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, insert

i try to write a website for library as an exercise. I have while loop to display all books in my database. If user is logged in and state(stan) of book(ksiazka) is free(Wolny) it shows button under book. After clicking it takes all free books to database and update their state as hired not only that one which user want. Here is the code, thanks.

```
$findbook2 ="select ksiazka.id_ksiazka, ksiazka.tytul, ksiazka.id_stan, autor.id_autor, autor.imie_autor, ksiazka.rok_wydania, autor.nazwisko_autor, stan.id_stan, stan.nazwa_stan FROM ((ksiazka inner join autor ON ksiazka.id_autor = autor.id_autor) inner join stan ON ksiazka.id_stan = stan.id_stan);";

$stan = mysqli_query($connect, $findbook2);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($stan))
{
    echo "Tytuł:" . " " .$row['tytul']." ". "Autor:" . " " . $row['imie_autor']." ". $row['nazwisko_autor']. " ". "Rok wydania" . " ". $row['rok_wydania'] . " ". "Stan ". $row['nazwa_stan']. " ";
    if(isset($_SESSION['id_czytelnik'])){

        if($row['nazwa_stan']=='Wolny'){

            echo '<form method = "GET" action = "ksiazki.php">';
            echo '<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Wypożycz"/>';
            echo '</form>';                                             

            if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
                $id_czytelnik = $_SESSION['id_czytelnik'];
                $id_ksiazka = $row['id_ksiazka'];
                $data_oddania = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days'));
                $wstaw_ksiazke = "INSERT INTO `wypozyczenie`(`id_wypozyczenie`, `id_czytelnik`, `id_ksiazka`, `id_pracownik`, `data_wypozyczenia`, `data_oddania`) VALUES ('','$id_czytelnik','$id_ksiazka',2,NOW(),'$data_oddania')";

                if(mysqli_query($connect, $wstaw_ksiazke)){
                    $update = "Update ksiazka set id_stan = 3 where id_ksiazka = '$id_ksiazka'";
                    if(mysqli_query($connect, $update)){
                        echo "Wypozyczyłeś książkę";
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

    echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask your question. What problem does the code have?

Comment: I really can't follow what you've written and I can't even see a question, can you please clarify?

Comment: The problem is the code takes all books with state free to database and updates it as hired. It should work not in this way. For every book with state free is button after clicking this button this code update all books with state free but it should update only one

Comment: For example i have 5 books with free state in database i click to hire book 1 and after clicking button i have all 5 books as hired and don't now how fix it.

Comment: This is open to a serious SQL injection; use a prepared statement.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Consider the statement `if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))` which is always true inside your while loop after clicking submit as it is not unset anyway.It causes repeated execution of a statement while the Array is not empty.